# Get-Package | Uninstall Package doesn't work, no error

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, google-chrome, package

I try to list all applications, choose one of them and uninstall it, kind of like in control panel.

```
$package = get-package | Out-GridView -PassThru

Get-Package -Name $package.Name | Uninstall-Package
```

when I execute this and choose Google Chrome, it doesn't do much.
this is probably a dumb question, not new to PowerShell but not veteran either

Comment: Do you get any insights if you do `Uninstall-Package -Verbose` instead?

Comment: I'll have a look

Comment: It tells me : VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Uninstall Package." on target "Package 'Google Chrome' with version '105.0.5195.127'.".

But then same thing my google chrome still exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Uninstall-Package` cmdlet can't delete entries where "ProviderName" is "Programs"
Example:

```
get-package *chrome*

Name                           Version          Source                           ProviderName
----                           -------          ------                           ------------
Google Chrome                  105.0.5195.127                                    Programs
```

In general Programs with "ProviderName" property as "Programs" are ones that are  installed via **.exe** .

If you want to uninstall packages with PackageManagement/PowerShellGet they need to be installed by PackageManagement/PowerShellGet.

Alternative would be to install Chocolatey Package Provider and it should be able to delete it

Comment: thanks for information, I will see what I can do. This tool is supposed to work for many people so I am not sure if Chocolatey will be the solution